# Manage "window-local" buffers in Vim

Tags: vim

**Clarification**: A "window-local buffer" in this context just means a buffer once loaded into a specific window, any other buffer not ever loaded into that window is not a "window-local buffer".

I had some ruminations on ways managing buffers earlier and I think having a "window-local" buffer list would provide an extra way managing buffers. By saying that, I'm not interested in ways managing buffers already provided by Vim.

And it seems the solution is straightforward by recording "window-local" buffers manually like `autocmd BufWinEnter * call add(w:buffers, expand('%'))` and providing corresponding interfaces to the "window-local" buffer list `w:buffers`.

Do you find this useful? And any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Windows and tab pages are abstractions built on top of buffers to provide more means to organize your workspace and workflow. They are useful, of course, but they *shouldn't* be used as the basis for your workflow. Think in "buffers", use windows and tab pages when they are useful.

Comment: @romainl Sorry for the previous misleading question. I'v done some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

To list all open buffers use this:

```
:buffers
```

To open buffer #5 use this:

```
:buffer 5
```

You can use the following mapping to combine the two commands:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :buffers<CR>:buffer<Space>
```

How to use this convenient mapping:

- press `F5`
- enter a buffer number
- press `<Enter>`

More reading [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching). (*search for "switching by number"*)

Comment: I would like to add that rather than numbers, you can also use `:buffer` with buffer names and is much more convenient that way, it also provides completion to make things even more simpler.

Comment: `:buffer 5` can further be shortened to `:b5`

Answer (score 1):

The buffer list is global. You can have a *window*-local argument list (with `:arglocal`), and then use commands like `:next` to navigate through them.